# Using multiple DDLs within a transaction in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

Does anyone know the reason, yugabyte-specific or otherwise, that I cannot alternate between truncating and inserting within the same transaction?

These steps:

1. Truncate a table.
2. Insert a row into that table.
3. Truncate again.
4. Insert another row into the table.

Result in this error on the final step:

```
ERROR: Operation failed. Try again.: Unknown transaction, could be recently aborted: e415ae05-0d46-42f5-b18d-f27b344b5642 (SQLSTATE 40001)
```

[Disclaimer]: This question was first asked on the YugabyteDB Community Slack channel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In YugabyteDB, currently 'truncate' is not transactional. The recommendation would be to avoid using:

a) truncate inside of a multi-step transaction

OR

b) running truncate concurrently with our read/write operations on the same table.

To my knowledge other distributed SQL databases also either:

a) do not support truncate (like Google Cloud Spanner). See [Does Cloud Spanner support a TRUNCATE TABLE command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43266590/does-cloud-spanner-support-a-truncate-table-command)

OR,

b) they support truncate, but not in transactional manner.

We do plan to restrict this restriction in future. In the near term perhaps

`delete from T;`

can be used as a workaround; this is a bit heavier weight than using truncate, but will be transactional.